How to do number formatting on Line Chart in Powerbi connected with Azure Synpase?
I have a chart in Powerbi chart which is connected with Azure Synapse data. This chart has 2 bars and 1 line on it. I want to display the numbers in 0.0M format or 000.3K format (if less than 1 M). For bars, it worked fine. But for the line, how to format please suggest steps. Refer to top numbers above line in the below image

